# Getting the error "positional argument required" even after providing the arguments

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

This is the exact error I am getting. The `MusicBot.on_wavelink_track_start()` function requires 1 positional argument 'player' when using the `MusicBot.play()` function even though I have provided it. I have checked the position of the arguments in documentation. `MusicBot.on_wavelink_track_end()` requires 2 arguments 'player' and 'reason' when using the `MusicBot.stop()`.

```
INFO       - discord.client  : logging in using static token
INFO       - discord.gateway : Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: 97560cd953************ac231ca3cb).
INFO       - bot             : User: Bot#2026 (ID: 1085520364706222181)
2023-03-24 12:11:43 INFO     cogs.music {} is ready
ERROR      - discord.client  : Ignoring exception in on_wavelink_track_start
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\the00\Desktop\bot\env\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 441, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: MusicBot.on_wavelink_track_start() missing 1 required positional argument: 'player'
ERROR      - discord.client  : Ignoring exception in on_wavelink_track_end
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\the00\Desktop\bot\env\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 441, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: MusicBot.on_wavelink_track_end() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'player' and 'reason'
```

My code -

```
class MusicBot(commands.Cog):
    vc : wavelink.Player = None
    current_track = None
    music_channel = None
    history = None

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.history = list()
    
    async def setup(self):
        """ Connecting to lavalink """
        node = wavelink.Node(uri="http://localhost:2333", password="mypass")
        await wavelink.NodePool.connect(client=self.bot, nodes=[node])
    
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_wavelink_node_ready(self, node: wavelink.Node):
        logger.info(f"{node.players} is ready")
    
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_wavelink_track_start(self, track:wavelink.YouTubeTrack, player:wavelink.Player):
        await self.music_channel.send(f"{track.title} started playing")
    
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_wavelink_track_end(self, track:wavelink.YouTubeTrack, player:wavelink.Player, `your text`reason):
        await self.music_channel.send(f"{track.title} finished")
        await self.history.append(track.title)
    
   @commands.command()
   async def join(self, ctx):`your text`
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    self.music_channel = ctx.message.channel
    if channel:
        self.vc = await channel.connect(cls=wavelink.Player)
        await ctx.send(f"Joined {channel.name}")
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

[`on_wavelink_track_start` and `on_wavelink_track_end` uses `wavelink.payloads.TrackEventPayload` as only argument now](https://wavelink.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wavelink.html#event-reference):

```py
async def on_wavelink_track_start(payload: TrackEventPayload):
    ...

async def on_wavelink_track_end(payload: TrackEventPayload):
    ...
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).